# qsort with function comparator different

Tags: c, qsort

I need help with function COMPARE in qsort. Compare the array G->orden but comparing with the order element that serves as an index in another array and how insert G in compare.

```
struct VerticeSt {
    u32 nombre;
    u32 color;
    u32 grado;
    u32 *vecinos;
};
struct GrafoSt {
    u32 n;
    u32 m;
    u32 nc;
    u32 delta;
    Vertices v;
    u32 *orden;
};

int Compare(const void* a, const void* b) {
     u32* x1 = (u32*) a;
     u32* x2 = (u32*) b;
     if(G->v[G->orden[x1]] < G->v[G->orden[x2]]) 
         return -1;
     else
     .
     .
     .
}
qsort(G->orden, G->n, sizeof(u32), Compare);
```

Comment: Can you please tell what are you getting, instead of what ?

Comment: You're using a pointer as an array index? Isn't your compiler complaining about that?

Comment: I can not get any results since I can not call the COMPARE function with parameters that are different from the G-> order. The elements of G-> order [i], would serve me as an indication in another arrangement, rather in G-> v [G-> order [i]]. I still can not handle it well with this idea. I can not resolve that Compare can receive me in addition to the two const a b, a Grafo G.

Comment: Compare in qsort recieve two parameters const void a , const void b. I need tha Compare recieve trhee parameters const void a const void b Grafo G.

Comment: If `G` is not part of `a` and `b`, then the only way to get access to `G` is by making `G` a file-scope static variable, or just a plain old global variable.

Comment: The `typedef` for `Vertices` is missing — are you making it a pointer: `typedef struct VerticeSt *Vertices;`?  Do you have `qsort_r()` available to you?  It looks like it would help you enormously.  Beware, the version of `qsort_r()` on Linux (GNU C Library) is different from the version on *BSD and macOS — they have equivalent functionality, but different argument orders.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming (from your call to `qsort()`) that `G->orden` points to the base of an array of values of type `u32` with length `G->n`, then the values passed to your comparison function will be pointers to elements of that array. Your `Compare()` function should cast the `void*` pointers passed to it to pointers to the type that it knows about, and then dereference those to get the actual values that it will compare.

Here's a short program that shows the whole thing in action:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned long u32;

int Compare(const void* a, const void* b) {
    u32 x1 = *(u32*)a;   // Get the array element that a points to
    u32 x2 = *(u32*)b;   // Get the array element that b points to

    if (x1 < x2)         // Compare the values and return result
        return -1;
    else if (x1 == x2)
        return 0;
    else return 1;
}

void printArray(char* label, u32* a, int n) {
    printf("%s", label);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("\t%lu", (unsigned long)a[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    u32 array[5] = {9, 3, 27, 18, 6};
    printArray("unsorted: ", array, 5);
    qsort(array, 5, sizeof(u32), Compare);
    printArray("  sorted: ", array, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the result:

```
unsorted:   9   3   27  18  6
  sorted:   3   6   9   18  27
```

> Compare in qsort recieve two parameters const void a , const void b. I need that Compare receive three parameters const void a const void b Grafo G.

In that case, `qsort()` probably isn't quite the right function for you. There are also `qsort_r()` and `qsort_b()`. `qsort_r()` takes an additional `void*` parameter that's also passed into the comparison function, and that sounds closest what you need — you could pass a pointer to your `G` in this parameter. `qsort_b()` takes a comparison block (a.k.a. closure) instead of a function, and that block can capture context from the caller.

Comment: You can also just `return (x1 > x2) - (x1 < x2);` Same thing, just shorter.

Comment: You could also `return (long)x1 - (long)x2;`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I like that! But I think for the purposes of the example, doing it the long way better illustrates the general case... OP's (or a future reader's) values could be something completely different.

Comment: @selbie `(long)x1 - (long)x2` may overflow leading to UB and certainly incorrect results with large values.  `(x1 > x2) - (x1 < x2)` does not have that problem.